# Getting total amount in a column

Tags: java, vaadin

I have the below method

```
 public void footerSet() {

    // Calculate total sum
    double totalSum = 0.0;
    // double totalMargin = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ic.size(); i++) {
        Item item = ic.getItem(ic.getIdByIndex(i));

        try {

            double valuetotal = Double.parseDouble((String) item
                    .getItemProperty("Amount").getValue());

            totalSum += valuetotal;
            System.out.println(">>>2222 : " + totalSum);

            // System.out.println(">>>2222 : " + totalSum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // System.out.println("not a number");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ProductTableGlobal.setColumnFooter("Outlet", "Total");
    ProductTableGlobal.setColumnFooter("Amount", String.valueOf(totalSum));

}
```

and the type is below

```
    icLoaded.addContainerProperty("Outlet", String.class, null);
    icLoaded.addContainerProperty("Amount", String.class, null);
```

and in the model i have the below

```
     //NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

      double totalAmounts = totalAmount;
     passTable.getContainerProperty(UID, "Amount").setValue(
                numberFormat.format((totalAmounts)));
```

When i try to sum up the totals i only get the first column as the total. See below logs

> > > 2222 : 460.0
> > >            not a number

```
>>>2222 : 460.0
>>>2222 : 460.0
```

See below stack trace

INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT

> > > 2222 : 460.0

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2,336.00"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at com.zocha.reports.TaxByOutlet.footerSet(TaxByOutlet.java:280)
at com.zocha.reports.TaxByOutlet.OutletSalesView(TaxByOutlet.java:84)
at com.zocha.reports.TaxByOutlet.enter(TaxByOutlet.java:62)
at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:571)
at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:526)
at valo.ValoThemeUI$5.buttonClick(ValoThemeUI.java:551)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:978)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:287)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

>>>2222 : 460.0
>>>2222 : 460.0

Note: 2,336.00 is the second value that needs to be added and so on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are setting column footer inside loop your following code should be outside the loop,

```
ProductTableGlobal.setColumnFooter("Outlet", "Total");
ProductTableGlobal.setColumnFooter("Amount",String.valueOf(totalSum));
```

---

Secondly you are casting to `String` and using `toString` as well use one of them,during your second iteration value you are getting can not be *parsed* to double so that you got *not a number* which you are printing int `catch` block so to get more info about exact problem for that you should use `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block.

```
2222 : 460.0
not a number
```

---

SO ,from stacktrace we can see that the value you are getting from `Amount` property is

```
2,336.00
 ^
```

So this value can not be parsed to double due to `,` in `String` the easy solution can be the use of [`#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) and you better use null check before parsing so you can avoid null pointer excaption.

```
double valuetotal=0.0;
if(item!=null && item.getValue()!=null){
  String tempString = item.getItemProperty("Amount")
                          .getValue()
                          .toString()
                          .replace(",","");
  valuetotal=Double.parseDouble(tempString);
}
```

Comment: i have edited and changed as per your changes, but the issue still persists.

Comment: i have added the stack trace. Note: 2,336.00 is the second value that needs to be added and so on

Comment: Thanks alot. Its now working well. NB - i have added ProductTableGlobal.setColumnFooter("Amount",
    numberFormat.format(totalSum));